# How to handle very long coxph formula in R?

Tags: r

I have a coxph formula that involves more than 100 variables.  It is almost impossible to fit the formula in one line.  In glm(), I use paste0 to construct the formula and pass it into glm.  Looks like that this approach does not work with coxph().  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you use the `as.formula` function to convert the string to formula? Are you using all the other variables in your data.frame in your model? You can also use the `response ~ .` syntax to indicate "all other variables"

Comment: You can also `response ~. - variable` if you want to include all your variables within the data-set except for a few.

Comment: Thanks, the as.formula works better for me.